# Problem installing MRU.vim

Tags: vim

I downloaded the MRU.vim file and put it in my /.vim folder (along with my other working plugins).

When I try to use

```
:MRU
```

i get

```
"E492: Not an editor command: MRU"
```

I'm using VIM v7.0 on Mac OSX Snow.

Any thoughts?

**update**
I installed MacVim which has an option to "Choose a vim script to run". When i load MRU from there MRU starts working.

I've added mru.vim to the autoload folder yet still no joy.

Comment: Check the output of `:scriptnames` to see if the plugin is even loading.  If it's not there, you need to check the installation steps and make sure you didn't miss something.

Comment: its not in the :scriptnames . Also, since its a .vim file i dont think there is any special instructions to install it. Or am i missing something? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy it to the .vim/plugin folder?

Answer (score 0):

probably file is in dos format

you can see this by writing

`:set ff?`

if result is `dos`

than try using:

`:set ff=unix`